# Multiple option value's into database without JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Is it possible to POST ALL value's from a list through a foreach/for loop so I can insert those value's into MySQL:

First list:

```
require('pdoConfig.php');
try {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM PRIJS";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);

    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<option value=" . $row['PRIJS_ID'] .">" . $row['NAAM'] . " - €  " . $row['PRIJS'] .  "</option>";
    }
    $pdo = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This generates the first list:

[image]

The user can then click on the blue/orange button to (re)move items from both lists. At the user submits the list and ONLY the items from the second list should be submitted. Now ive tried several things with while loops but I get nothing because I think It only sends the selected item whereas I need ALL the items.

Comment: Yes it is possible. What did you try ? And I think you generate this list, so why do you want to store something you generate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using this way

rename the select menu on the html to this

```
<select name="test[]">
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="NO">No</option>
<option value="Ok">OK</option>
</select>
```

on the php

```
<?php
    foreach ($_POST['test'] as $item)
    {
    print "$item<br/>";
    }
?>
```

You should convert the select menu  name to array and fetch the content of array by using foreach

Answer (score -1):

You don't need Javascript if you know that you need all the values from the listbox. The easiest way to do this is to set all the options as selected when you create the options.

For example, it will look like this if you're using PHP.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="values[]">
  <?php 
     while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
     {
        $option = $r['thing'] ;
        echo  "<option value="$option" selected>$option</option>";
     }
  ?>

</select>
```